# How to get records after a certain time using SQL datetime field (not by whole hour)

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I am on SQL Server 2017.
If I have a datetime field (systime), how do I get just records created later than a certain time, ignoring the date altogether? An example of the field would be: 2015-05-20 18:23:49.000

I want to find any records at or after  5.30 PM  or  another scenario, no later than 7.25 PM. How would I be able to get either result?

The below query would give me the result based on the whole hour.

```
select *
from myTable
where datepart(hh, sysdate) > 17
```

Here are more date time examples

```
2015-08-30 21:34:52.000
2015-09-30 20:20:34.000
2015-11-03 19:53:34.000
2015-12-08 22:49:58.000
2016-02-01 18:47:50.000
2016-02-05 18:41:19.000
2016-02-05 18:41:20.000
```

Comment: You have a datetime _column_.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: the myDateField contains both date and time

Comment: Sample Date is: 2015-05-20 18:23:49.000

Comment: [edit] clarifications into your question please. And provide enough sample data to illustrate the problem i.e. if I understand correctly you need data that covers multiple dates.

Comment: Don't be lazy, edit your question and some more sample data, along with the matching expected result. Make it easy to assist you, and you'll get better help.

Comment: correct I want to see anything after for example 17.30       or   maybe even 17.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if time part is after 17:

```
Select * from myTable where convert(char(8),myDatetimeField,114) > '17:30:00';

Select * from myTable where convert(char(8), myDatetimeField, 114) <= '19:25:00';
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting this error when going with this attempt:

`select * from ord where cast(sysdte as time) >= 17.30`
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Operand type clash: time is incompatible with numeric

If I try single quotation marks, around the time, 
`select * from ord where cast(sysdte  as time) >= '17.30'`
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I am on SQL Server 2017

Comment: Neither `17.30` or `'17.30'` is what Crying demonstrated here @dnk. Check the literal value(s) they used again; you'll see that they are different.

Comment: @dnk, I edited that would work even in SQL server 2000.

Comment: @Larnu, what do you mean by "Crying" ?

Comment: That's what autocorrect thought your name should be, @Cetin . Apologies.